# Область безопасности в Wildfly 10 и пользователи в базе данных

Tags: java-ee, настройки, wildfly

Подскажите как настроить.
Выдает ошибку, что пользователь не существует.
Есть ли у кого рабочий вариант?
Все вроде настраиваю как описано.

`web.xml` все прописано (на `GlashFish` все работает).
База создана, пользователи добавлены, роли созданы.
Коннект c базой `OK`.

***jboss-web.xml***

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/secureDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

***standalone.xml***

```
<security-domain name="secureDomain" cache-type="default"> <authentication>
<login-module code="Database" flag="required">
<module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasourc
es/UserDS"/>
<module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd f rom Users where username=?"/>
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from UserRoles where username=?"/>
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/> </login-module>
</authentication> </security-domain>
```

Comment: А еще у Вас пробел в запросе на слове FROM (select passwd f rom Users where username=?)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в файле **jboss-web.xml**
Так бы работало в **Wildfly 8**

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/secureDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

В **Wildfly** начиная с версии **9** `Security Domain` объявляется без префикса `java:/jaas/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>secureDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```